# User preference to turn off Firefox starting with two tab

Tags: firefox, mozilla, user-preferences

I've been all over the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) trying to find out which command line arguments or userpreferences will prevent firefox from starting with two tabs open and also stop asking would I like to share usage statistics.

Here's a screenshot
[image]

What command line argument or user preference can I set to stop Firefox browser from starting like that when I provide the `-new-instance` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the startup pages, you might want to try setting `startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional` and `startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional` to `about:blank`.

The bar that asks to share usage statistics is called the "data choices infobar", and it's controlled by the preferences documented [here](https://gecko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/toolkit/components/telemetry/telemetry/internals/preferences.html).

You could programmatically "view" the data policy, by setting `datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyNotifiedTime` to something like `1483520304570` (the output of `Date.now()`) and `datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAcceptedVersion` to 1. This will tell Firefox that you saw the bar. You could still disable data sharing using `datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled`, if interested.